# How to define a macro that takes the definition of a macro as an argument

Tags: macros, programming

We would like to define a macro `\ellipsis` that takes four argument and has the following behaviour:

```
\ellipsis{x^{#DUMMY#}}{0}{5}{+}
```

and outputs:

[image]

the pattern string `#DUMMY#` (which doesn't have to be this exact string) has to be replaced by the second and third argument. So the first argument is the definition of a macro all by itself.

---

We have tried a couple of things but always end up using two different macros to obtain the desired behaviour. For example doing

```
\newcommand{\ellipMacro}[1]{x^{#1}}
\newcommand{\ellip}[4]{\csuse{#1}{#2}#4\ldots #4 \csuse{#1}{#3}}
```

This uses the control sequence `\csuse` from the package *etoolbox* (we are fine with using any packages).

We would like to do this in just *one* command, thus, the definition of the inner macro (`x^{#DUMMY}`) needs to be placed within the definition of the larger macro.

Please include any ideas on how to do this you might have.

Comment: I do not understand what dummy is supposed to do in this macro. From your definition `\ellipsis{x^{#DUMMY#}}{0}{5}{+}` there is nothing left to question inside of dummy as to what it does.

Comment: `#DUMMY#` is a placeholder, it should be substituted with the second and third arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an adaptation of my answer at [How to make a command to automate creation of prime factorization-like products?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448389/)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\elliptic}{O{i}mmmm}
 {% #1 = item to substitute
  % #2 = main term
  % #3 = first index
  % #4 = last index
  % #5 = operation
  \group_begin:
  \lucas_elliptic:nnnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
  \group_end:
 }
\tl_new:N \l__lucas_elliptic_term_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { NV }
\cs_new:Nn \lucas_elliptic:nnnnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__lucas_elliptic_term_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { #1 } % search
   { \cB\{\cP\#1\cE\} } % replace
   \l__lucas_elliptic_term_tl % what to act on
  \cs_set:NV \__lucas_elliptic_term:n \l__lucas_elliptic_term_tl
  \__lucas_elliptic_term:n { #3 }
  #5 \dots #5
  \__lucas_elliptic_term:n { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\elliptic{x^{i}}{0}{5}{+}$

$\elliptic{x_{i}}{0}{5}{+}$

$\elliptic[k]{(x_{k}+y_{k}i)}{1}{n}{}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're happy to use `#1` for the placeholder, this can be simplified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\elliptic}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = main term
  % #2 = first index
  % #3 = last index
  % #4 = operation
  \group_begin:
  \lucas_elliptic:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new:Nn \lucas_elliptic:nnnn
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__lucas_elliptic_term:n { #1 }
  \__lucas_elliptic_term:n { #2 }
  #4 \dots #4
  \__lucas_elliptic_term:n { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\elliptic{x^{#1}}{0}{5}{+}$

$\elliptic{x_{#1}}{0}{5}{+}$

$\elliptic{(x_{#1}+y_{#1}i)}{1}{n}{}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the two `\cs_new:Nn` be changed to `\cs_new_protected:Nn`, in an ideal world?

Comment: @frougon Not necessarily.

Comment: Neither `\lucas_elliptic:nnnnn` (1st example) nor `\lucas_elliptic:nnnn` (2nd example) can produce a meaningful result when used in an expansion-only context, right? Defining them with `\cs_new_protected:Nn` would be a clear indication of this fact to anyone reading their definition. No need to delve into their implementation to discover it. What do you gain here by *not* using `\cs_new_protected:Nn`? Do you fear that with `\cs_new_protected:Nn`, people would be encouraged to write calls inside `\edef` or so where the *arguments* are not adequately protected against expansion?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

For the example given where the argument comes at the end of the placeholder, you do not need to define any internal command, but for the general case the form `\ellipsisb` takes as the first argument the body of any one-argument command definition. This allows the 0^2...5^2 form shown at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

\newcommand\ellipsis[4]{#1{#2}#4\cdots#4#1{#3}}

$\ellipsis{x^}{0}{5}{+}$

\newcommand\ellipsisb[4]{%
\def\tmp##1{#1}\tmp{#2}#4\cdots#4\tmp{#3}}

$\ellipsisb{x^{#1}}{0}{5}{+}$

$\ellipsisb{{#1}^2}{0}{5}{+}$



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I don't understand what you want but as far as I can see you don't need `\csuse` here and can define:

```
\newcommand\ellip[4]{{#1}^{#3}#2\dots#2{#1}^{#4}}
```

This way $\ellip x+04$ and  $\ellip y-{-1}2$, respectively, produce

[image]

If you really do need a fancier version that supports a macro then I suggest not putting the macro in the exponent and, instead, just replace `x^` with `\csuse{#1}`:

```
\newcommand\fancyellip[4]{\csuse{#1}{#3}#2\dots#2\csuse{#1}{#4}}
```

so that now $\fancyellip{xint}-{1}2$ produces

[image]

for an appropriate definition of `\xint`.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\ellip[4]{{#1}^{#3}#2\dots#2{#1}^{#4}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\fancyellip[4]{\csuse{#1}{#3}#2\dots#2\csuse{#1}{#4}}
\newcommand\xint[1]{\int_{0}^{#1}x\,dx}

\begin{document}

  $\ellip x+04$

  $\ellip y-{-1}2$

  \bigskip

  $\fancyellip{xint}-{1}2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are using two `\newcommands` to get the ellipsis, I clearly stated that I want it to be all within just one definition.

Comment: @LucasVaca Sorry, but from your question  it is not clear to me what you want. Can you add more detail? The definition `\ellip` in my code is also one command, and seems to produce your desired output, so I don't even understand your comment.

Comment: I would like to not have to use another `\newcommand` in order to produce another ellipsis. In my question, `\ellipsis` is only defined once and can be used to define more than one macro. In your example you would have to define a new different macro for each different ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

My macro

```
\replaceiandreplicate{<term with i>}%
                     {<loop-start-index>}%
                     {<loop-end-index>}%
                     {<separator>}%
                     {<end index>}
```

presented in the discussion [Loop code for repeated sums](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449487/118714) and in the discussion [How to make a command to automate creation of prime factorization-like products?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448436/118714) might be of interest to you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%    \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange, \UD@removespace
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@removespace{}\UD@firstoftwo{\def\UD@removespace}{} {}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has no leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@firstoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is a
%%                               space-token>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is not
%%                               a space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB.#1 }{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB{}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB#1 {%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#1{}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  { #1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \DefineReplacementMacro{<replacement-macro>}%
%%                        {<internal helper-macro>}%
%%                        {<single non-explicit-space/non-explicit-brace-token to replace>}%
%%
%%  defines <replacement-macro> to fetch two arguments,
%%  #1 = <replacement for item to replace>
%%  #2 = <token sequence with item to replace>
%%  , and to deliver after two expansion-steps:
%%  <token sequence with all instances of 
%%  <single non-explicit-space/non-explicit-brace-token to replace> replaced 
%%  by <replacement for item to replace>. >
%%
%% Internally an <internal helper-macro> is needed.
%%
%%  (!!! <replacement-macro> does also replace all pairs of matching 
%%       explicit character tokens of catcode 1/2 by matching brace-tokens!!!
%%       Under normal circumstances this is not a problem as under normal
%%       circumstances { and } are the only characters of catcode 1 respective 2.)
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\DefineReplacementMacro[3]{%
  \newcommand#2{}\long\def#2##1#3{}%
  \newcommand#1[2]{%
    \romannumeral0\UD@ReplaceAllLoop{##2}{##1}{}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ReplaceAllLoop[5]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ #3}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{#1}{%
       \expandafter\UD@ReplaceAllLoop
       \expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}{#2}{#3 }{#4}{#5}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
            \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@ReplaceAllLoop
            \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{#2}{}{#4}{#5}%
        }{#3}}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ReplaceAllLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}}%
        {#4}{#5}%
      }{%
       \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNoReplacement
       \romannumeral0\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoReplacement[6]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{#5#1#6}%
  {%
    \expandafter\UD@ReplaceAllLoop
    \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#3}{#4#1}{#5}{#6}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@ReplaceAllLoop
    \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#3}{#4#3}{#5}{#6}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@ReplaceAlli -- Replace all "i" in undelimited Argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ReplaceAlli{<replacement for i>}{<token sequence with i>}
%%   yields  <token sequence with all i replaced by replacement for i>
%%
%%  <replacement for i> may contain i.
%%
%%  (This routine does also replace all pairs of matching explicit 
%%   character tokens of catcode 1/2 by matching braces!!!)
%%
%%  The letter "i" as item to replace is hard-coded.
%%  You cannot replace öetters other than I with this macro.
%%.............................................................................
\DefineReplacementMacro{\UD@ReplaceAlli}{\UD@gobbletoi}{i}%
%%
%%=============================================================================
%% \replaceiandreplicate{<term with i>}%
%%                      {<loop-start-index>}%
%%                      {<loop-end-index>}%
%%                      {<separator>}%
%%                      {<end index>}
%%
%% e.g., 
%%
%%  \replaceiandreplicate{p_i^{\epsilon_i}}{1}{3}{\cdots}{n}
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\replaceiandreplicate[5]{%
   \romannumeral0\expandafter\expandafter
                 \expandafter            \UD@Exchange
                 \expandafter\expandafter
                 \expandafter{%
                 \UD@ReplaceAlli{#5}{#1}%
   }{%
     \replaceiandreplicateloop{#3}{#2}{#1}#4%
   }%
}%
\newcommand\replaceiandreplicateloop[3]{%
  \ifnum#1<#2 %
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
  \else
   \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \fi
  { }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter{%
       \UD@ReplaceAlli{#1}{#3}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\replaceiandreplicateloop
      \expandafter{\number\numexpr\number#1-1\relax}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\parindent=0ex

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
$\replaceiandreplicate{x^{i}}{0}{0}{+\ldots+}{5}$
\end{verbatim}

yields:\bigskip

$\replaceiandreplicate{x^{i}}{0}{0}{+\ldots+}{5}$

\bigskip\hrule

\begin{verbatim}
$\replaceiandreplicate{\if i0\else+\fi x^{i}}{0}{4}{}{5}$
\end{verbatim}

yields:\bigskip

$\replaceiandreplicate{\if i0\else+\fi x^{i}}{0}{4}{}{5}$

\bigskip\hrule

\begin{verbatim}
$\replaceiandreplicate{\ifnum i=-2 \else+\fi x^{\ifnum i<0(i)\else i\fi}}{-2}{4}{}{5}$
\end{verbatim}

yields:\bigskip

$\replaceiandreplicate{\ifnum i=-2 \else+\fi x^{\ifnum i<0(i)\else i\fi}}{-2}{4}{}{5}$

\bigskip\hrule

\begin{verbatim}
$\replaceiandreplicate{p_{i}^{\epsilon_{i}}}{1}{3}{\cdots}{n}$
\end{verbatim}

yields:\bigskip

$\replaceiandreplicate{p_{i}^{\epsilon_{i}}}{1}{3}{\cdots}{n}$

\bigskip\hrule

\begin{verbatim}
$\replaceiandreplicate{\if in+\fi p_{i}^{\epsilon_{i}}\if in\else+\fi}%
                      {1}%
                      {3}%
                      {\cdots}%
                      {n}$
\end{verbatim}

yields:\bigskip

$\replaceiandreplicate{\if in+\fi p_{i}^{\epsilon_{i}}\if in\else+\fi}{1}{3}{\cdots}{n}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please don't nest calls to  `\replaceiandreplicate` within the first argument of `\replaceiandreplicate`.  ;-)